# Count de la misma columna dos valores diferentes

Tags: mysql, mysqldb

Estoy usando MYSQL, y Tengo una tabla "informe"

con los campos.  (tareasrealizadas, idUsuario, fecha, descripcion).

el campo "tareasrealizadas" inicialmente esta como NULL, esto significa que no ha realizado esa tarea.
cuando realiza esa tarea, esta columna puede tener cualquier numero mayor a 0.

Las consultas individuales funcionan

Estoy intentando sacar

1. todas las tareas de los usuarios en un rango de fechas:

> ```
> SELECT count(tareasrealizadas) from informe where fecha >= 0 and
> fecha <= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'  group by idUsuario
> ```

2. las tareas realizadas de los usuarios en un rango de fechas:

> ```
> SELECT count(tareasrealizadas) from informe where fecha >= 0 and
> fecha <= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' and
> tareasrealizadas >= 0  group by idUsuario
> ```

3. las tareas fatalntes de los usuarios en un rango de fechas:

> ```
> SELECT count(tareasrealizadas) from informe where fecha >= 0 and
> fecha <= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' and
> tareasrealizadas is null  group by idUsuario
> ```

Pero no he podido sacar en una misma consulta.
el total de todas las tareas,  las tareas asignadas, y las faltantes en un rango de fecha organizadas por usuario.

Alguien me podria ayudar explicandome como debo realizar esta consulta? muchas gracias.

Comment: Las consultas individuales funcionan bien?

Comment: Ademas pon tu codigo

Comment: Lo que usted necesita, son unas *agregaciones condicionales*.